# I got a MSI Leopard GP60 2PE with two SSDs? :O

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, laptop, ssd, msi

I have a laptop with two SSDs and one is almost completely empty: I have 500gb+250gb and the 250gb SSD has only 1gb of used space which is only a few folders like this: `$RECYCLE.BIN/Papirkurv`, `$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-18`, `$RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-509494386-3903922194-131465332-500`, `a15a0964caf0a134cee7/MRT.exe` and `System Volume Information` and a weird `mrt.exe` does anyone on this forum have any idea if it's safe to install Ubuntu on that SSD?

I have experimented if I can boot the other by disabling the UEFI mode and change it to Legacy so that means I can it seems but not sure if I can format the 2nd SSD without screwing up the MSI PC...

Comment: @RodSmith: The question isn't “How do I install Ubuntu on my SSD?”. It's “Is it *safe* to install Ubuntu on my SSD?”

Comment: If you're concerned about data loss, only you know what's on that SSD -- unless perhaps this is pre-installed stuff, in which case the manufacturer knows -- but you haven't said what the make or model is. If you're concerned about Ubuntu malfunctions, there should be none. It's unclear why you're concerned; you need to clarify your question.

Comment: $RECYCLE.BIN/Papirkurv, $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-18, $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-509494386-3903922194-131465332-500, a15a0964caf0a134cee7/MRT.exe & System Volume Information

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly safe *for Ubuntu* to be installed on and run from that SSD. Linux don't need to stinkin' `.exe` files. ;-P

If you want to know, whether a Windows installation (e. g. in a dual-boot environment) will be affected by the removal of that file, you should ask on [SuperUser](//superuser.com/). The people here are really good at removing Windows and installing Ubuntu, but they don't know know (or pretend to not know) much about Windows. It would also be off topic.

Comment: Well the locked folders worry me the most I think its hidden stuff in them! :S Also that .exe file is something that Defender made it seems...

Comment: What's a “locked folder”?

Comment: $RECYCLE.BIN/Papirkurv, $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-18, $RECYCLE.BIN/S-1-5-21-509494386-3903922194-131465332-500, a15a0964caf0a134cee7/MRT.exe & System Volume Information

Comment: Those are directories created by Windows to hold files moved to recycle bin before permanent deletion. What makes you say, they're "locked"? Yes, they have the "system" and hidden" flag, that have no equivalent in Linux and Unix, but I can access them here without a problem. In the end, Linux and Ubuntu don't care about those directories.

Comment: So it can be completely deleted and removed to install Ubutnu 14.04 and it will work along with the 8.1 in UEFI with no issues? Can i still choose which OS to boot when I start or do I have to swap storage device each boot?

Comment: I feel the need to cite my own answer: “It's perfectly safe for *Ubuntu* to be installed on and run from that SSD. […] If you want to know, whether a Windows installation (e. g. in a dual-boot environment) will be affected by the removal of that file, you should ask on [SuperUser](//superuser.com/).” For your other questions about the installation procedure and the manner and safety of operating Windows and Ubuntu alongside each other, please the the question, of which yours is flagged as a duplicate. Spoiler: It's safe (if you don't act stupidly) and you don't need to swap any drives.

Comment: Yes its safe I have done it before but the UEFI and those weird files in the folder will not cause problems? If i delete the files on the 250gb SSD the Windows on the 500GB wont be damaged or harmed at all?

Comment: “If you want to know, whether a Windows installation (e. g. in a dual-boot environment) will be affected by the removal of that file, you should ask on [SuperUser](//superuser.com/).” In any case this part of your question is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.